# WorkManager OneTimeWorkRequest not working

Tags: android, background, coroutine, androidx

I have `WorkManager` that is used to send data over the network, however for some odd reason the `CoroutineWorker`'s `doWork`is not called.
Here's my code:

```
 val data = workDataOf(Constants.TAG to "newValue")

        val request =
            OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<CustomWorker>()
                .addTag(Constants.TAG)
                // Sets the input data for the Worker
                .setInputData(data)

                .setInitialDelay(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                // Set a backoff criteria to be used when retrying
                .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL, 30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()

        // Enqueue the request instance
        WorkManager.getInstance(this)
            .beginUniqueWork(Constants.TAG, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, request)
            .enqueue()
```

This is the code that initializes the WorkManager, and the code for the `CoroutineWorker`is this:

```
class CustomWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
        Log.d("PLEASE", "doWork called!")

        // Get the FCM token from the input data
        val newToken = inputData.getString(Constants.TAG)

    }
```

The Log is not called inside the `doWork`, why is that?

Comment: Could you elaborate with which context you are calling your code, i.e. "what" is `this` at the moment you get an instance of the WorkManager?  

(One additional remark: You might also use `enqueueUniqueWork` instead of using `beginUniqueWorker`& `enqueue`.)

Comment: this doesn't work for me either. What's the solution so far ? @BBB in my simple code, I'm not even setting `uniqueTag` so calling simple `enqueue` but same result

Comment: still not working for me

Comment: @Andrey have you managed to sort this out? I'm experiencing similar problem

Comment: @Renjith yes I had to downgrade the work manager version to 1.0.0